# What to return on an IndexOutOfBoundsException exception?

Tags: java

I have the following method

```
private ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

public User getUser(int index) {
    try {
        return allUsers.get(index);
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // What should I return here?? Say that you want index 0 and no User
        // exists in the ArrayList allUsers, what should I then return? The
        // method needs a User to be returned 
    }
}
```

And I'm not sure how to do here, I'm sure thats its an easy fix, but what should I return in the catch block? Eclipse is complaining that a `User` must be returned.

Comment: Just return null.

Comment: or don't catch the exception

Comment: Let the exception get passed up; the caller of the `getUser` method is at fault.

Comment: Frankly I'm a little surprised that this question has received three upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would throw an exception if no user is found. This exception is caught when the method is called. You could modify the code here to use a custom exception if you want. Something like:

```
public User getUser(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(index >= allUsers.size()){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("User doesn't exist");
    }
    return allUsers.get(index);
}
```

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is unchecked. You don't need to declare it.

Comment: This is true, I placed the code in case he wanted to throw a custom excepction instead of the out of bounds one, maybe he wants to create a UserNotFoundException or something, and he'll know where to place it. But your observation is definitely important to note.

Comment: @JanDvorak Adding a throws clause explicitly documents that this method will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException; it is not required, but it might be helpful if this is actually an API with other users.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel IIRC, the correct way is to add a `@throws` clause in the Javadoc but not in the function header itself.

Comment: @JanDvorak You can do both, Eclipse will even complain (if you have the right settings enabled) if you add a `throws SomeRuntimeException` without also documenting it with a `@throws SomeRuntimeException`; the other way around it doesn't complain for `RuntimeExceptions`. But you are right there is no further benefit.

Answer (score 15):

My general opinion is that you should **never catch an exception that you don't know how to handle**. Particularly in this case, since `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException` and thus does not need to be caught - you can just as well let it propagate up the call stack. The caller is asking for an object by list index, so presumably has some idea of which index to ask for -- then, throwing or allowing a thrown IndexOutOfBoundsException to propagate seems perfectly natural.

The only other obvious option would be to swallow the exception and `return null`, but I really don't like such an approach for such flagrant errors on the part of the caller when there is no sensible return value. You could also return a special `User` instance (refer *null object pattern*), but even that does not absolve the caller of the responsibility to check what was returned. Depending on the interface and implementation of `User` such checks may be trivial or not, but it still needs to be done somewhere.

If you want to be clear that the method can throw an exception, just say so:

```
public User getUser(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException { ... }
```

Or like @[Bela Vizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433475/486504) suggested, wrap it in an IllegalArgumentException (which also is a RuntimeException).

And as pointed out by @[lc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433465/486504), it's better to check first yourself if the object exists before trying to access it. Handle yourself the error case that you *expect* rather than relying on the `get()` method call to throw an exception. You should still be clear about the fact that the method *might* throw such an exception, however, if for example the collection is modified between the check and return. With multithreaded software on multi-core CPUs, stranger things have been known to happen.

Answer (score 11):

Ask yourself the question: "what should you return if you want index 0 and no User exists?" and return whatever you answer.

If you have no answer, you should either re-throw the exception or not be catching it in the first place.

Note that often times, the answer would be to return `null`, if it is *acceptable behavior* to ask for a non-existent User.

---

Side comment: It is usually considered "good practice" to not rely on catching exceptions, but to test for error conditions first. In your case you are trying to `get` an invalid object index first then *reacting* if the getter blows up. Instead, I would recommend to test the `index` parameter first (make sure it is at least zero and less than the length of `allUsers`), and if it fails the test to do something (return null or throw your own exception).

Comment: +1, particularly for the so-called "side comment" which is really useful in this case.

Comment: +1; note that some exceptions (Scanner -> InputMismatchException) just _can't_ be prevented.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't know about that particular example, but that's when you *have* to resort to catching a thrown exception. In this particular instance, preventing the exception from being thrown in the first place in the huge majority of cases (*not* necessarily 100% foolproof, though) is quite trivial.

Comment: Is 'asking for permission' more favored in the Java community? I'm more of a Python guy and I've always been more favorable to the opposite 'ask for forgiveness'.

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities. Some of them depends on your beliefs.

- You can throw an IllegalArgumentException since the passed argument
  is not valid.
- You can throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException.
- If you want to make sure clients (caller of this method) have to take
  care of it, you can even declare a checked exception (define your
  exception class extending Exception), because
  IllegalArgumentException and IndexOutOfBoundsException are runtime
  exception which means you don't have to prepare yourself explicitly.

I usually check if the index is in range, if not return null and mention in the javadoc that it can return null if...

Comment: +1, especially because I had to laugh about the 'depends on your beliefs' :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't listen to Eclipse.

You have two choices and both of them can be good or bad, depending on the circumstances.

1. You can return `null`.
2. You can just re-throw the exception (or rather, not even catch it at all), asking the calling method to deal with it.

There are several more variations, but the basic choice is between the above two: handle the problem in place or delegate the task to the caller.

From that code alone it's impossible to tell which one is the right solution, only you can know what is more appropriate to the situation.

Whichever choice you take though, it's better to check the index manually (`0<=index<allUsers.size()`) and not relying on `RuntimeException`s for normal program behaviour.

Comment: Eclipse 'complains' because every path needs to return something. So he should listen to that (otherwise it will never compile).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OP wrote that "Eclipse says a User must be returned". That's blatantly not true, you can also throw an exception.

Comment: It might be better to explain what Eclipse (or the compiler) tries to convey instead of simply saying not to listen to it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's exactly what I'm doing in the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `index` is user input, just let `IndexOutOfBoundsException` propagate and catch it farther up at a point where you can display an error message.

In fact, you could first validate `index` against `allUsers.size()` before even trying the lookup to do the same thing. User input should generally be validated at the earliest point possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would return `null`, however, if you feel your app might crash because of that, you can simply return a "nobody" User like this:

```
return new User("nobody", ...);
```

And handle that case outside the function.

Another alternative is to throw the exception and handle it outside.

Comment: No. Just - **NO**. If you use a null object pattern, *at the very least* expose a public, read-only `NoSuchUser` instance that you return and which can be compared against. Or expose a public method somewhere to check whether a `User` instance is a real User or not. Don't make one up as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

1. Return a `null`. Do this if the user could reasonably enter any index
2. Don't catch the exception. Do this if it is totally unexpected that the user could enter bad data, in other words, the input is being checked already so it's a "programming error" (or bug) that caused the situation
3. Throw a checked exception. Do this if you feel the calling code can and should deal with the problem